# JSoup returns an invalid HTML

Tags: html, jsoup

I'm working with JSoup 1.11.3 from Maven. I'm trying to make absolute relatives href, my code is in the following:

```
public String updateHrefs (String htmlContent, String baseUrl, String currentUrl) {
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links) {
      String absHref = link.attr("href");
      System.out.println("URL before " + absHref);
      if (absHref.equals("")) {
          absHref = baseUrl;
      } else if ((absHref.length()>1) && absHref.substring(0, 2).equals("//")) {
          absHref = absHref;
      } else if (absHref.equals("http")) {
          absHref = absHref;
      } else if (absHref.substring(0, 1).equals("/")) {
          absHref = baseUrl + absHref;
      } else if (absHref.substring(0, 1).equals("#")) {
              absHref = baseUrl + currentUrl + absHref;
      } else {
          absHref = baseUrl + "/" + absHref;
      }
      System.out.println("URL after " + absHref);

      link.attr("href", absHref);
    }
    return doc.outerHtml();
}
```

At the end I pass the result to a html-to-pdf engine and it returns the error that a

```
 <p>
```

tag is not closed. I tried the html-to-pdf engine with the original html and it works: is it possible that there is an issue in JSoup? thanks

Comment: Can you share the HTML?

Comment: @Alessandra, you can get absolute href using `String absHref = link.absUrl("href");`

Comment: @Alessandra, Is there any reason to construct absolute href yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about absUrl, it works. I noticed that if there are any br tag the parser writes them without closing and html-to-pdf closes with other tags.

Comment: I found the solution, the problem is that my html-to-pdf engine wants xml and doesn't like <br>. I added  
  
 doc.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);  
  before to return doc and it works!